# CakePhp Config.timezone gives me wrong time

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

If I use in core.php

```
Configure::write('Config.timezone', 'Europe/Paris');
```

Time displayed will be 2 hour less than

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

Should I set something else in my core.php ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please alwas mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly! Also show the actual unaffected code in question.

Comment: Sorry. Cakephp 2.x and the code affected is a simple date('Y-m-d H:i');

Comment: 2.x is _not_ an _exact_ version number, CakePHP version numbers consist of at least 3 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the comment above that configuration value:

> `Config.timezone` is available in which you can set users' timezone string.
>   If a method of CakeTime class is called with $timezone parameter as null and `Config.timezone` is set,
>   then the value of `Config.timezone` will be used. This feature allows you to set users' timezone just
>   once instead of passing it each time in function calls.

The `Config.timezone` configuration value only applies to the `CakeTime` utility class, wich will use that value in case no timezone is explicitly being passed to it.

In order to configure the timezone used by built-in PHP functions you'll have to use `date_default_timezone_set()`.

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html#configure**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html**